# How to get the average for Day Wise in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows with below three columns

```
Date      table_name    count
1/6/2023    table1    5161454381
1/6/2023    table2    286759521
1/6/2023    table3    43756630
1/6/2023    table4    27032087
1/6/2023    table5    44189394
1/6/2023    table6    63475022
1/5/2023    table1    5362300063
1/5/2023    table2    289459360
1/5/2023    table3    59042261
1/5/2023    table4    37256587
1/5/2023    table5    55511764
1/5/2023    table6    77917391
1/4/2023    table1    5316875841
1/4/2023    table2    282894202
1/4/2023    table3    57226525
1/4/2023    table4    36150830
1/4/2023    table5    54099874
1/4/2023    table6    75897787
1/3/2023    table1    5301932742
1/3/2023    table2    281278819
```

I need to add a average for each day as well as each table. As an example,
Lets say the Date is 2023-01-06 and table is table1, I need to get the average for last 2 week same week day. Mean that the average of 2023-01-06(friday) is caclulcated by using 2022-12-30 and 2022-12-23. Both are Friday. Then it should displayed. Then I need to show it as a pivot table.

[image]

I tried as below, but average taking part is not correct, can some one help to change that part to get the required output?

```
SELECT
    t1.table_name as table_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN table_date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY) THEN count END) AS '$date04',
    MAX(CASE WHEN table_date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) THEN count END) AS '$date03',
    MAX(CASE WHEN table_date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) THEN count END) AS '$date02',
    MAX(CASE WHEN table_date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN count END) AS '$date01',
    t2.AVG
FROM tbl t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT table_name, AVG(count) AS AVG
    FROM tbl
    where table_date >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY)
    GROUP BY table_name
) t2
    ON t2.table_name = t1.table_name
where table_date >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 4 DAY) and t1.table_name not in ('table7')
group by t1.table_name;
```

Comment: Please provide DDL for this table, andor use `YYYY/MM/DD` as format for dates (not `MM/DD/YYYY`). Also please do NOT use [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) for column names.

Comment: How many column do you expect in result? In your example you used last 4 dates. Do you want to put column for each date that occurs in your table or only last 4 dates?

Comment: The avg for 03-01-2023 is put in `avg1` then what is put in `1/3/2023` column

Comment: @mr.loop total 8 columns should need as shown.1/3/2023 column should put the just Count, Avg1 should put the average value for past two weeks for same day of week. Mean that the average of 2022-12-27 and 2022-12-20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change column name from `Date` to something else. I used `Datee`

Try

```
WITH  cte1 AS (SELECT DISTINCT(table_name) FROM tbl)
SELECT table_name,
(SELECT count FROM tbl WHERE Datee=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND tbl.table_name=cte1.table_name) AS '$date04',
(SELECT AVG(count) FROM tbl WHERE Datee IN (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3+7 DAY),DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3+14 DAY)) AND 
tbl.table_name=cte1.table_name) AS avg1,
(SELECT count FROM tbl WHERE Datee=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND tbl.table_name=cte1.table_name) AS '$date03',
(SELECT AVG(count) FROM tbl WHERE Datee IN (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2+7 DAY),DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2+14 DAY)) AND 
tbl.table_name=cte1.table_name) AS avg2,
(SELECT count FROM tbl WHERE Datee=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND tbl.table_name=cte1.table_name) AS '$date02',
(SELECT AVG(count) FROM tbl WHERE Datee IN (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1+7 DAY),DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1+14 DAY)) AND 
tbl.table_name=cte1.table_name) AS avg3,
(SELECT count FROM tbl WHERE Datee=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY) AND tbl.table_name=cte1.table_name) AS '$date01',
(SELECT AVG(count) FROM tbl WHERE Datee IN (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0+7 DAY),DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0+14 DAY)) AND 
tbl.table_name=cte1.table_name) AS avg4
 FROM cte1;
```

Also, you will probably need dynamic sql if you want to use date value like `03-01-2023` as actual column name

Comment: Great...Better if you can elaborate what mean by INTERVAL 3+7 DAY clause

Comment: @Pathi ex for `05-01-2023`, we need dates `29-12-23` and `22-12-23`. But today is `08-01-23` so first we move to 05 through 3 + (29 through 7) or (22 through 14).

Comment: @Pathi We could directly write +10 and +17, but I wrote like that for clarity

Comment: `Date` is not a reserved word in MySql

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure If I follow you correctly when you describe what you desire.

That's why I made a guess ....

```
SELECT
  table_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` = '2023-01-03' THEN A ELSE 0 END) as Avg3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` = '2022-12-20' THEN A ELSE 0 END) as Avg3_Min2wk,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` = '2023-01-04' THEN A ELSE 0 END) as Avg4,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` = '2022-12-21' THEN A ELSE 0 END) as Avg4_Min2wk,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` = '2023-01-05' THEN A ELSE 0 END) as Avg5,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` = '2022-12-22' THEN A ELSE 0 END) as Avg5_Min2wk,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` = '2023-01-06' THEN A ELSE 0 END) as Avg6,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `Date` = '2022-12-23' THEN A ELSE 0 END) as Avg6_Min2wk
FROM (
  SELECT 
    table_name,
    `Date`,
    AVG(`count`) as A
  FROM tbl
  GROUP BY table_name, `Date`
  ) x
GROUP BY table_name
```

output:

| table_name | Avg3 | Avg3_Min2wk | Avg4 | Avg4_Min2wk | Avg5 | Avg5_Min2wk | Avg6 | Avg6_Min2wk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table1 | 5301932742.0000 | 0.0000 | 5316875841.0000 | 0.0000 | 5362300063.0000 | 0.0000 | 5161454381.0000 | 0.0000 |
| table2 | 281278819.0000 | 0.0000 | 282894202.0000 | 0.0000 | 289459360.0000 | 0.0000 | 286759521.0000 | 0.0000 |
| table3 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 57226525.0000 | 0.0000 | 59042261.0000 | 0.0000 | 43756630.0000 | 0.0000 |
| table4 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 36150830.0000 | 0.0000 | 37256587.0000 | 0.0000 | 27032087.0000 | 0.0000 |
| table5 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 54099874.0000 | 0.0000 | 55511764.0000 | 0.0000 | 44189394.0000 | 0.0000 |
| table6 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 75897787.0000 | 0.0000 | 77917391.0000 | 0.0000 | 63475022.0000 | 0.0000 |

Comment: Hi. Thanks. But this is not what I mean. I don't want to specifically mention any date. the logic should align with the Date. and also above provided table structure also incorrect

Comment: About "also above provided table structure also incorrect", please read [Help others reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Help%20others%20reproduce%20the%20problem). You  did not provide the correct structure, so I made a guess ...